# How to prevent `M-<digit>` from invoking `digit-argument`?

Tags: key-bindings, commands

In Windows, it is possible to type the Alt key together with some number to obtain the character associated to that number.
This is useful when your keyboard is not properly mapped or is missing that character. In Emacs, doing this triggers a command repetition, as the correct way to print a character from a number is to use `C-q number`.

Beyond trashing the screen,
if the users types `M-number` and does not see the desired character, they will most likely type again, and the ultimate effect is to freeze Emacs. This happens because, as soon as they type a non-number key, they trigger a number of repetitions too high

I can think of two possible theoretical solutions to avoid this incident: one is to disable the bindings associated to the repetitions, and the other is to rewrite the repetition function so that, if the number is, say, above 1000, then you are asked a confirmation before executing it, or the function simply returns.

As for the latter, one could rewrite the function `digit-argument` so that it returns when the `digit` variable is higher than some threshold.

I am not sure if there is a better way.

Comment: Just what is the question?

Comment: Avoiding involuntary command repetitions, by disabling or modifying the function triggering them

Comment: What is "the character associated to that number" for `M-0` to `M-9`?  And if your OS was actually intercepting those key strokes, Emacs would be receiving that resulting character rather than the modified digit, so it's not clear that what you've described is actually accurate.

Comment: I asked because "involuntary command repetitions" wasn't very clear, to me. I translated the title to something closer to Emacs-speak. What I think you're talking about is the use of  `Alt` + a digit key to provide a numeric **prefix argument** to a command or another key.

Comment: @Drew: fine, thank you

Comment: The  [alt code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alt_code) is a known Windows feature. For example, type Alt+38, using the numpad with Num Lock on, and you get an `&`. This feature is not implemented at driver level, therefore Emacs is able to intercept it, so you will see `C-u 38-` in the echo area for the sequence above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you want <kbd>Alt</kbd> + a digit key to insert the character of that digit. In Emacs, <kbd>Alt</kbd> + `3` is written `M-3` (Meta 3).

If you want `M-3` to insert the character `3`, and so on then do this:

```lisp
(define-key esc-map [?0] "0")
(define-key esc-map [?1] "1")
(define-key esc-map [?2] "2")
(define-key esc-map [?3] "3")
(define-key esc-map [?4] "4")
(define-key esc-map [?5] "5")
(define-key esc-map [?6] "6")
(define-key esc-map [?7] "7")
(define-key esc-map [?8] "8")
(define-key esc-map [?9] "9")
```

If you want such keys to do nothing then do this:

```lisp
(define-key esc-map [?0] nil)
(define-key esc-map [?1] nil)
(define-key esc-map [?2] nil)
(define-key esc-map [?3] nil)
(define-key esc-map [?4] nil)
(define-key esc-map [?5] nil)
(define-key esc-map [?6] nil)
(define-key esc-map [?7] nil)
(define-key esc-map [?8] nil)
(define-key esc-map [?9] nil)
```

Variable `esc-map` has as its value the keymap for Meta keys.

You can use the <kbd>Esc</kbd> key in place of the <kbd>Alt</kbd> modifier key. Hit `ESC` and *then* a digit, `ESC 3` etc. in place of `M-3` etc. And the above rebindings also bind key `ESC` followed by a digit.

---

I don't advise doing any of this, however. I recommend that you learn the Emacs use of `ESC` and the `M-` prefix, including for digits. Trying to have Emacs mimic inferior habits from MS Windows (or whatever) isn't worth it, IMHO. Those are just habits to grow out of, IMO.

Comment: Thanks, the `esc-map` is what I was missing, which closes the issue. Regarding "bad habits", I once found myself in a situation where I inadvertently triggered too many repetitions in a comint buffer, froze Emacs and lost my work. So, I propose also my solution based on advising `(digit-argument)`.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution, where you cannot make more than 1000 repetitions.

```
(defun my-digit-argument (x)
  (when (> prefix-arg 1000)
    (setq prefix-arg nil)
    (message "Too many repetitions")))
 
(advice-add 'digit-argument :after #'my-digit-argument)
```